# EF Core encoding with Firebird 2.5

Tags: c#, delphi, .net-core, entity-framework-core, firebird

I am migrating a legacy system made in Delphi + FireDac to C# + EF. As it is a legacy system, there is already a database with many records (Many records without encoding information).

When I get records that contain special characters using C# + EF, the characters are not displayed correctly.

How can I fix this problem?

**C#**

[image]

**Delphi**

[image]

**MainWindow.xaml.cs - ButtonClick**

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string appPath = AppContext.BaseDirectory;
    string connectionString = $"database=localhost/3050:{appPath}\\database\\test.fdb;user=sysdba;password=masterkey";          
    using (AppDbContext con = new AppDbContext(connectionString))
    {
        Product p = con.Products.First();
        lblText.Text = p.Name;                
    }
}
```

**AppDbContext.cs**

```cs
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public AppDbContext(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

        optionsBuilder.UseFirebird(_connectionString);
    }
}
```

**Product.cs**

```cs
[Table("PRODUCTS")]
public class Product
{
    [Column("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("NAME")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

[Complete C# project code](https://github.com/ofelipegodinho/SOposts/tree/master/CSharp/EntityFramework/FirebirdEncoding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For firebird, most of the times, issues with special characters can be handled with the use of CharSet UTF-8. Within `connectionString`, you may need to include `charset=utf8`.

Added update:

Thanks to @Felipe Godinho for the feedback, it seems `charset=win1252` has been found to be another valuable option of CharSet that is worth to try when handling legacy database system that is running on Firebird.

Comment: I had already tried to pass charset=utf8 and yet the problem continued. I tried with charset=win1252 and problem solved. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad you solved the problem. It seems that `win1252` is another good option to try when working around the issues with Firebird :)

Comment: win1250 and win1252 - AFAIR they are eastern and central European codepages - are worth trying for European legacy projects. But they would most probably be wrong choice for ex-USSR regions (win1251 Russian codepage would be better guesswork), Greek, Far Eastern nations, etc. So... this suggestion is not universal

Comment: Proper approach would be to check the charset/codepage of the very specific column you are reading. Or, lazier approach, assuming there was no column-level override and all columns merely inherit database-wide settings, one has to `select * from RDB$DATABASE` - see Appendix D at https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html

Comment: BTW, if the Delphi application is written properly, then the `charset` parameter (or `lc_ctype` or something) should be specified in the database object properties there too, in form's option or in connection establoiching code, just to be peeped and copied into .NET app with all other relevant settings

Comment: @Arioch'The The problem is that it is a legacy database. It was created with `charset=none`, so in delphi's connection settings `charset=none` is set. And according to item 3.5.3 of the documentation, when this occurs, the client application is responsible for handling encoding. When I migrated to C# I used `charset=none` as the first alternative and I had the same problem.

Comment: @FelipeGodinho Delphi before 2009 (non-Unicode) used ANSI-xxxx Windows codepages (MBCS, each letter is usualy one byte, or more) strings. `int GetACP(void)` Win32 API function. Delphi since 2009 used UTF-16 strings internally, just like Java and C#. Since you quote FireDAC not AnyDAC - you use some Delphi version of 2015 or later. Even then, even if the DB itself has no charset - then charset could be in column definitions themselves. And on top of it, the connection may have it. Personalyl I would use something like fbprofiler.sf.net and check the connection sequence form Delphi app to FB srv

Comment: `charset=utf8 and yet the problem continued. I tried with charset=win1252` this OTOH indeed looks like the text fields were stored as raw binary. But then, are you absolutely sure your Windows has 1252 as default ANSI codepage, not 1250 or some other? It can be checked in Registry, probably in some Control Panel (not sure), or from Delphi (for a new graphics VCL app you only need create main form `OnShow` event handler and  put there `ShowMessage('Code Page is ' + IntToStr(GetACP()));` command ).

Comment: Anyway, it will remain very fragile. Proper way would be to dump all the `schema` (meta-data, declaration part) of the database into SQL script, then changing the script to explicitly declare the charset (UTF8 or Win1252 or anything) and collation, then creating new database and "pumping" data (decades ago there was IBDataPump tool, today there are others probably similar tools too, or you can do it yourself, if to sort all the tables for dependencies) from old to new. This "we mean cp1251 text in our raw binary fields" implicit requirement remains a hidden landmine waiting to blast.

Comment: one day someone will tell you "we gave you money to write new not-legacy app, and now you must support all non-European letters too, overnight" and you would have to convert the DB to explicit UTF8 anyway :-) Also, maybe DB conversion and fixing Delphi FireDAC charset property would make an application somewhat less legacy too :-D

Comment: Thank you very much for the class, knowledge is never too much. Even more knowledge so well explained. Very good! I understand and agree with you about the changes that must be made to the database. I actually use a recent version of Delphi, but the database was created before that version. And I'm just migrating a query tool that will only list records. The whole part of CRUD will not be changed, before your comments I had already talked to the DBA about the lack of encodings. The bomb is now in his hand ;D