# Accessing Windows located Firebird Database from Docker contained Django App

Tags: django, docker, firebird2.1

I am trying to access Firebird Database files located in C:/ drive from Docker Contained Django Application.

I am using Python fdb package for accessing this.

```
self.conn = fdb.connect(   host='192.168.0.108', port=3050, database='/FIREBIRD_DB/TEST.FDB', user=usr, password=pswd)
```

It generates error:

```
Exception: The location of Firebird Client Library could not be determined.
```

How can I access the machine's Firebird Database from Docker Contained Django app?

Comment: Thank you very much. Installing libfbclient2 into ubuntu just resolved the issue.

Comment: 2.1 FB line is EoL, if there is no incompatibility in your app, you better install FB 2.5.9 Server on the host machine instead - it will read FB 2.1 database files, and is generally a bit faster, bit more flexible, and more useful features (like TraceAPI). Unless you would absolutely have to transfer the database file back to 2.1 server somewhere else

Comment: FB Server is not in my scope. It is a third-party application of which is mostly running on 2.1 FB version. For now, currently, everything seems working smoothly.

Comment: do you specify connection properties charset? if you cooperate with other apps, then explicitly declaring text codepage rather than using default `NONE` ( storing text as raw binary ) would be suggested (recent example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63693951/ ). Granted, with FB lacking TraceAPI it is rather hard to peep into someone else's program...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to:

1. install and run Firebird Server on the machine with DB file, and
2. install client libraries of Firebird (fbclient.dll on Windows, probably lib_fbclient.so on Linux, etc) with the CPU architecture same as CPU architecture of your Python.exe on the machine running Django in Python, and
3. make sure your Python can find those libraries (%PATH% environment variable in Windows, LD configuration in Linux, etc).

Read "Client Installation" chapter in Quick Start guide at http://firebirdsql.org/en/server-packages